# Laravel 4.2 - I have fixed 'unserialize(): Error at offset' Error, but now How can I work around without changing Laravel Core?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Deleting all sessions files in app/storage/sessions will fix it normally. But if it happen to production this will destroy every Users sessions just because of one User session corrupted. You can force this error if you delete some characters from the content of the active session file.

My Solution was to modify Laravel core.
This was a 4 lines codes in 2 files. A method readFromHandler is called in Store class in Illuminate\Session\Store.php, I Added a global variable to catch the SessionId (that is the real file name of the session file):

```
protected function readFromHandler()
{
    $data = $this->handler->read($this->getId());

    $GLOBALS['sess_id'] = $this->getId();

    return $data ? unserialize($data) : array();
}
```

And there is a file that handle all Errors in Laravel before even getting the App ready: \Illuminate\Exception Handler.php . I Changed method handleEror to this:

```
public function handleError($level, $message, $file = '', $line = 0, $context = array())
{
    //Ensure the error is about unserialize() and is coming from Store.php
    if(strpos ($message, 'unserialize(): Error at offset') !== false && 
        strpos ($file, 'Store.php') !== false)
        unlink('../app/storage/sessions/'.$GLOBALS['sess_id']);

    if (error_reporting() & $level)
    {
        throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $level, $file, $line);
    }
}
```

This is acceptable in an urgency case, but I know changing the Core is not the way to go. I'd like to know is somebody can change this approach to achieve the same goal. Hint: I need a way to access Session Id (session filename) outside Laravel Vendor Core (ex: in app, global, etc.) and catch that Error way before Laravel App is setup because this App::error() is not reached when this Error occurs.

Comment: A hack is not the solution, you need to find out how the data is getting corrupted in the 1st place - this is not normal behaviour

Comment: I know and I'm not satisfied, and that's why I come up with a question. In fact, I think the data is corrupted when my laptop freezes, slow down and then I'm force to shutdown holding power. Or I can modify manually the session file which will cause the same error. On a Ubuntu server production this error is almost impossible, but you never know...

Comment: I'd be minded to think that unless you've seen this happening in production or staging, it's not worth spending time on.

Comment: As above, if this is just happening in development, on one machine, then i wouldnt bother trying to fix it in code - then problem is with your computer.

Comment: I tried extending the Session, but in vain. I think laravel won't let us catch the sessionId in App::error no matter what, because the error occured before any App class in the proper flow is ready to use. That's a laravel bug, not ours. So I totally agree with both of you guys @halfer and Steve, 1 day spending time for nothing is enough. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is extend the session driver (it appears you are using the file session driver at the moment), here is the relevant part of the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/extending#session

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I tried it, but this error occurs way before Laravel App is ready, so App::error will never catch it. Since it's a development environment issue, I took the advice of 2 guys on my question. That's a laravel bug, so I think any proper work around is limited by laravel itself.